# Tumblr / Lightbox / Infinite Scroll

Tags: scroll, lightbox, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I'm currently working on a photo blog on Tumblr that is using the 'Infinite Scroll' Script to load all the content on the main page without having to scroll between the pages.
After adding the 'LightBox' code to the script, it works but **only for the first 10 images** on the homepage.

I assume the infinite scroll script is changing something in the img settings...

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I try this [Auto ThickBox Plus](http://attosoft.info/en/blog/auto-thickbox-plus-1-6/) jquery plugin.

I have had this problem.

I have tried many plugins, fancybox, lightbox,colorbox and others, but only this one worked with infinite scroll.